# Encrypt HBase at-rest data in Cloud

Tags: encryption, hbase

I am pretty new to HBase and have been assigned a task to move our infrastructure to cloud. Our HBase data contains some customer information and hence needs to be encrypted while at-rest. I am already reading this: **Transparent Encryption of Data At Rest** (http://hbase.apache.org/book/ch08s03.html#hbase.encryption.server)

It looks like a good solution except the fact that we have to store the password as plain text on each node. Is there a way to avoid this? Like store the password at just one location and source it to each node or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Where is it written that password should be stored in plaintext ? data is being encrypted by key that could be driven by KMS server

Comment: @sashank For HDFS alone, there is option to keep the keystore file in KMS server and not for Hbase. Still now we need to keep it in the localstore.