# Encryption at REST for Hbase data

Tags: encryption, hbase

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_server_side_configuration_3

I have checked the URL in which it'll encrypt the data based on the Java `java.security.KeyStore`. But we need to keep the file `.jks` which contains master key for all the hbase servers (all master and Region servers have to have this file).

**NOTE:** Also the password to open the file has been given in `hbase-site.xml`.

For HDFS alone, there is option to keep the keystore file in the KMS server and not for HBase. Still now we need to keep it in the local store.

I don't need KMS option. I need something to keep the value in common place has to be accessed instaed of having same file in the all servers.

Is there any method/custom class available to get master key from the common storage like DB/redis/Zookeeper?

#### UPDATE #1

Someone has asked similar question but no solution for that: [Encrypt HBase at-rest data in Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369427/encrypt-hbase-at-rest-data-in-cloud).